# What does Cs (as in ComputerInfo.CsName) mean when you run Get-ComputerInfo in powershell?

Tags: powershell, documentation

I've been digging through documentation and haven't been able to find where it mentions what it is actually short for. I assume it means Computer System but that's just a guess on my part. If anyone knows I would love to learn. It's nothing super important, just a nagging question I can't find a sure answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the developers can tell, but I'll hazard a guess. The reason is to differentiate operating system from computer system. Take a look at [cmdlet's source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/GetComputerInfoCommand.cs) code for further details.

The cmdlet gets its data from CMI class [CIM_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-operatingsystem). Since it also has Cs prefix for certain members, it is likely the cmdlet developer has used the same name to avoid confusion.